# Ceiling beam crack/split. Should I be worried?

Tags: ceiling, beam, crack

The house is a recent purchase and I repainted (including the ceiling) before moving in so not sure if this was pre existing.

I just saw this today and concerned it's a structural issue vs the normal wood beam splitting I've read about online. There are subsequent beams that have similar albeit smaller cracks. I tried to color code the images as best I can.

The red is the most concerning, followed by green and blue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do I need to call a pro out to inspect or am I overreacting?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are those solid or hollow?

Comment: That looks like drywall, not a wooden beam. It's hard to give any reliable answer not knowing what's inside.

Comment: I don't think these are "beams" at all.  I think they are ornamental, maybe hiding seams in the ceiling panels or maybe creating coffers. Not supporting any weight.    It's hard to tell what they are made of.  Parts look like wood, and I see small nails holding them to the wall and apparently holding the bottom part on.  But the cracks look like paint or plasterboard cracks so it's really hard to tell.  Have you tried banging on them with your hand or a hammer and/or drilling small holes to see what material comes out?

Comment: It could also be beams that have been boxed in with drywall for fire separation purposes....

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. One thing I realized is I need to get a lot smarter about my own house and your collective responses are helping me research the right topics /hopefully ask the right question in the future. It's an exposed/vaulted ceiling so those "beams" are definitely bearing some load from the roof. The next step is to fverify they are solid wood beams and what they've been boxed in with (just coats of paint or some plaster/drywall).

Answer (score 1):

IF those were wooden beams (which seems doubtful) the cracks are of no concern. They are in the top part of the beam, thus in compression, not tension. Two of them are more in the joint between ceiling and "beam" than "beam" for that matter.

If they are actually drywall over something (as suggested in a comment, pretty reasonably from the look of them) they are not structural and of no concern.

Comment: Agree - they look like joint tape that's coming loose, more than "cracks" in a beam.